# How do I set the working directory in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, datastructure

I'm learning QGIS and lovin' it.  But one thing that annooys me a little is is that each time I want to save data, the default directory is the QGIS folder under Program Files.

How can I set this, globally, for all my data?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS automatically stores and loads data to and from the directory last used.

So simply create a new data directory somewhere else in your file system, and QGIS will use that as default, unless the directory last used is deleted or removed (e.g. on a USB stick).

Comment: That's the behaviour that I thought it should exhibit, but it wasn't doing that for me. I'll go back to it and have another look.

Comment: It wasn't using the described behavior until I saved the project itself, then it started doing it

Comment: I have discovered that some tools do this and some don't. Many of the Processing tools use the last used directory. So, when I am working on multiple projects in a day, I am forever changing directories. It would be nice if each project remembered the last place it saved something. (Including Composer outputs).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Win7 etc, learn to use Recent Places, it will be a benefit for all the software you use.

Have your default folder view settings to 'details' with sort by date.   Also consider establishing shortcuts in folders or the next level of sophistication, Libraries, which are available from nearly all file dialogs. For instance I have a library 'GISData', which contains links to a lightweight folder of common gis data and a link to heavyweight drive of background imagery.

Comment: Are you saying the Recent Places item in the Windows Start menu? How does that change anything in QGIS settings so that work will be saved in a folder other than C:\Program Files\...QGIS\bin?